# Disable Alert boxes when site not found Gecko Fx VB

Tags: vb.net, alert, geckofx

I been searching around and cant seem to find anything relating to this. Basically i made a windowless app which uses the gecko webbrowser. Thing is, if i try browse to a site that does not exist. Example: www.gets.commmss, it will show me an alert box saying `www.gets.commmss could not be found. Please check the name and try again.` I dont want this to show as i handle these errors myself using the `navigated` & `NavigationError` handlers. Thing is, i cant seem to disable this annoying alert box! Any ideas much apprecited.

The geckofx version i am using is: GeckoFX v33.0.9.0

I am using visual studio 2012 and it is a windows form application.

Screenshot:[image]

This must be done via the app somewere as i dont think this is a javascript thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override the PromptService.Alert(). The following code works for GeckoFX 45:

```
public class NoPromptService : PromptService
{
    public override void Alert(string dialogTitle, string text)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Then run this after initializing GeckoFX:

```
PromptFactory.PromptServiceCreator = () => new NoPromptService();
```

I got this from an [older answer on the GeckoFX issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-29.0/issues/129/promptservice).

Comment: I am guessing thats c#? What would the correct code be for `PromptFactory.PromptServiceCreator = () => new NoPromptService();` in vb? I made a class and called it: NoPromptService. Inside i have `Imports Gecko

Public Class NoPromptService
    Inherits PromptService

    Public Overrides Sub Alert(ByVal dialogTitle As String, ByVal text As String)
        Debug.WriteLine(text)
    End Sub
End Class` Just not sure how to have it call that class. Thanks!

Comment: @irishwill200 Create a new function PromptServiceCreator that returns a new NoPromptService(). Then set PromptFactory.PromptServiceCreator = PromptServiceCreator().

Comment: Im not sure if i am following, could it be possible to update the answer with a VB solution please? In my form load i have the following: `GeckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("thestt.commss")
        Gecko.PromptFactory.PromptServiceCreator = PromptServiceCreator()` and i also have the function: `Function PromptServiceCreator()
        Dim val As New NoPromptService()
        Return val
    End Function` With this, the alert still shows but noticing the console i receive `A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in TestApp.exe`.

Comment: @irishwill200 Correction, you have to use: PromptFactory.PromptServiceCreator = AddressOf Me.PromptServiceCreator (Sorry, too long since I worked with VB)

Comment: Bingo!! Worked a charm, amazing! Thank you very much!:)

Answer (score 0):

VB.net GeckoFx Disable Alert

```html
Dim MyPath = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory
   Public Sub New()
        Xpcom.Initialize(MyPath + "\xulrunner")
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        Xpcom.ProfileDirectory = MyPath + "\profile"

        Gecko.PromptFactory.PromptServiceCreator = AddressOf PromptServiceCreator
    End Sub
    Function PromptServiceCreator()
        Dim val As New NoPromptService()
        Return val
    End Function
 
 
Public Class NoPromptService
    Inherits PromptService
    Public Overrides Sub Alert(ByVal dialogTitle As String, ByVal text As String)
        Debug.WriteLine(text)
    End Sub
End Class
```